# How can I add the current pathname to a href with a different url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently splitting a website up so the English version resides on the subdomain en. and the French version resides on the www.

Before doing this I have a drop down menu that selects the current language by appending the url with the language code so clicking 'English' will add /en/ after the .com and clicking 'French' will add /fr/ currently if the user chooses to change languages on a product page it will stay on the same page.

I would like to do the same but rather than using the current url and ammending the /en/ to /fr/ or vice versa it will add the current filepath to the end of the url in the href on the anchor tag.

```
<li>
    <a onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'en'); $('#language_form').submit();" href="javascript:;">
      <img alt="English" src="http://en.domain.com/filepath/gb.png"> English        </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/fr/" id="addURLlang">
      <img alt="français" src="http://en.domain.com/filepath/fr.png"> français        </a>
</li>
```

Above is what I have currently but this just takes the user to the french homepage. I tried to write a script to append the filepath to the url but this doesn't work, see below:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#addURLlang').attr('pathname');
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it helps but an example of one of the urls is en.domain.com/en/c/62/lenfance/ if french is selected I would like it to go to www.domain.com/fr/c/62/lenfance/ - i would like to take the /c/62/lenfance/ and append this to the href in the anchor tag

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks, Chris

Comment: `jQuery('#addURLlang').attr('pathname');` will print `undefined` to console when used. `.attr()` with one parameter would get you the value of **attribute pathname** if it was set like this: `<a id="addURLlang" pathname="something">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Qwerty, what would I put where the 'something' is in the pathname?

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to prepend the `href` of a `<a>` element, you can do it like this `$('#addURLlang').attr('href', "en."+$('#addURLlang').attr('href'))`. Not sure why would you need to use a custom parameter named `pathname`.

Comment: I see, so you have **incomplete** url in `<a>` and you want to change it at runtime according to which language is set!

Comment: Qwerty, yeah exactly .. sorry I didn't really know how to explain what I want to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process shows you how to get old `href`, alter it and put back. You can now do whatever substitution you need.

```
var element = $('#addURLlang');
var newUrl = $(element).attr('href') + 'c/62/lenfance/';

$(element).attr('href', newUrl);
```

You might need to play around with `.replace()` and such to both change 'www.domain.com' to 'en.domain.com' and append the url.

To change `www.` to `en.` and vice versa, you can use something like this

```
'http://www.domain.com'.replace(/(http:\/\/)?www\./, '$1en.' );
'http://en.domain.comm'.replace(/(http:\/\/)?en\./,  '$1www.');
```

To obtain current browsers address (url) do this

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.. just one query is it possible to take the newUrl from the current url as this will work dynamically, my idea was that users can translate the current page from english to french and vice versa

Comment: You mean from browser address or from an element's value? Yes, it is possible to take the value from anywhere.

Comment: from the browser address i mean so it works dynamically, thats what I was trying to using the $(location).attr('pathname') to do, I found it here: [link](http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery)

Comment: it is used like this: `var url = window.location.href;` Then you can perform replacements on the url and assign it to the anchor `$('#addURLlang').attr('href',newURL);`

Comment: @ChrisNaylor No problem, I hope this was of any help to you :)
If you want, see my profile and write me using some instant messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2015, js improved a lot. Here is a modern alternative:

```js
const appendPath = (href, path) => {
  if (!path) { 
    return href;
  }
  const url = new URL(href);
  url.pathname += `${url.pathname.endsWith('/') ? "" : "/"}${path.startsWith('/') ? path.slice(1) : path}`
  return url.href;
}
```

This solution uses:

- [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to handle the path extraction
- [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) to detect `/`
- [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to trim `/`

And here is some testcases:

```js
const cases = [
  ["http://a.b", "a", "http://a.b/a"],
  ["http://a.b", "/a", "http://a.b/a"],
  ["http://a.b/", "a", "http://a.b/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a", "a", "http://a.b/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a/", "a", "http://a.b/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a/", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a/a", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b/a/a/", "a/a", "http://a.b/a/a/a/a"],
  ["http://a.b?", "/a", "http://a.b/a?"],
  ["http://a.b/?", "a", "http://a.b/a?"],
  ["http://a.b?a=b", "/a", "http://a.b/a?a=b"],
  ["http://a.b/?a=b", "a", "http://a.b/a?a=b"],
  ["http://a.b", "a b", "http://a.b/a%20b"],
  ["http://a.b", "/a b", "http://a.b/a%20b"],
]

const appendPath = (href, path) => {
  if (!path) return href;
  const url = new URL(href);
    url.pathname += `${url.pathname.endsWith('/') ? "" : "/"}${path.startsWith('/') ? path.slice(1) : path}`
    return url.href;
}

cases.forEach(([url, path, expected]) => {
  const actual = appendPath(url, path);
  console.log(actual);
})
```